# The advantage of using __attribute__((aligned( )))

Tags: c, attributes

I found in more than one SIMD program the instruction  `__attribute__((aligned(16)))` . When I looked for an explanation I found

> The keyword **attribute** allows you to specify special attributes of
>   variables or structure fields.

Apparently variables have attributes. Are these attributes language-specific? what attributes can a variable have? where are these attributes stored?
Regarding the subject of aligned(16), I found this it

> causes the compiler to allocate [a variable] on a 16-byte
>   boundary

But is it mandatory for SIMD variables (**m128i for example) to be aligned on a 16 bytes?
If yes, I suppose this is the reason why we use __attribute**((aligned(16))) like so:

```
int a[16] __attribute__((aligned(16))) = {  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7, 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };

__vector signed int *va = (__vector signed int *) a;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html) like above are an extension (to the standard [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) language specification) provided by [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (and some few other compilers, e.g. [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)). The `aligned` attribute forces the compiler to align that variable (your `a` array) to the specified alignment. The [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc) lists the attributes you can give, and you could even extend your GCC compiler (with some plugin or some [MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/) extension; however MELT was abandoned in 2017) to add your additional attributes.

This `__attribute__((aligned(16)))` is indeed useful (on x86-64) for vector instructions like [SSE3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE3) or [AVX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions), since it is aligning to 16 bytes your `a`  array. It should enable the optimizing compiler to generate more efficient machine code. (You probably need also to give some optimization flags like `-mtune=native -O3` to `gcc`). So using it is useful (but not mandatory) for "SIMD" code.

Attributes are a compile-time annotation. Of course they change the behavior of the compiler, but such attributes do not exist at run-time (like C types do not exist at runtime neither).

If you didn't align your `a` array I guess that the compiler would have to emit additional instructions and they would run slower. BTW, you could compile with `gcc -O3 -fverbose-asm -S` (and [other](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86-64-Options.html) optimization flags) and, by looking inside the generated assembly code, see what the use of that attribute changes in the emitted assembly code. You could also benchmark your application (on Linux, see [time(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) and [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)...)

Comment: In `MSVC` you can write the declaration spec before the array: `__declspec(align(32)) int array[128];`. Is it equivalent of `int array[128] __attribute__((aligned(16)))`? Namely for MSVC you do before and GCC / CLANG you do after?

Comment: Does this work for member variables in a class too? For example class Foo{int a[32] __attribute__(aligned(8)); intb; }; Does this mean "a" gets aligned to 8 bytes?

Comment: Native SIMD instructions on at least Intel require alignment to the vector size so if it works without alignment it doesn't use SIMD instructions.

Comment: @nikhil_kotian Well I think it should do that.

Comment: Since I found this answer fairly high in my search results, an update: [C23 added the `alignas` keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignas) (it was `_Alignas` previously), and a [standard attribute syntax](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/attributes)